# Word problems involving Percentages

Tags: percentages, word-problem

**Question**

Marcy bought one pair of jeans at `70%` off and one blouse at `40%` off. If she paid `$12` more for the blouse than for the jeans and she spent a total of `$84`, what was the original price of the jeans?

I am having no clue on how to solve this problem? How to write the equations and solve for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- Suppose $B$ was the final price of the blouse and $J$ the final price of the jeans.

  - Can you translate "she paid $\$12$ more for the blouse than for the jeans" into an equation involving $B$ and $J$?
  - Can you translate "she spent a total of $\$84$" into an equation  involving $B$ and $J$?
  - Can you solve these to find $J$?
- Suppose $j$ was the original  price of the jeans.

  - Can you translate "Marcy bought one pair of jeans at 70% off" into an equation involving $j$ and $J$?
  - Can you solve this to find $j$?

Comment: One equation will be 0.3j+0.6b = 84,where j and b are the original prices, but how to translate "she paid $12$12 more for the blouse than for the jeans"?

Comment: What do you think $B-J$ or $0.6b-0.3j$ would represent?

Comment: The amount by which the cost of the blouse is more than the cost of the jeans?

Comment: And that is $\$12$

Comment: thanx a lot man...Now I have two equations to solve for, I could come up with that first equation but was not able to see this one `0.6b−0.3j`.

Comment: I now realize how much I suck in writing equations!!!

Answer (score 1):

The idea for "word problems" is to turn the information into mathematical statements (often, equations) about unknown quantities, and then use mathematical methods to solve for the unknown quantities.

The unknown quantities are the prices of the the jeans and the blouse. Because there are two prices for each (before and after the discounts), let's be definite and choose the variables

$$J = \textrm{original price of jeans}$$
$$B = \textrm{original price of blouse}$$

(note that, in the end, we are being asked to find the value of $J$).
If we need to represent the discounted prices of these items, we don't need new variables. We know the discounted prices are

$$0.30J = \textrm{discounted price of jeans}$$
$$0.60B = \textrm{discounted price of blouse}$$

(remember, $0.70J$ is taken off the  price of the jeans, so only $0.30J$  remains to be paid; similarly for the blouse).

Now represent the facts as statements.

First, the discounted cost of the blouse (in dollars) is $12$ more than the discounted cost of the jeans:

$$\underbrace{0.60B}_{\textrm{disc. blouse price}} = 12 + \underbrace{0.30J}_{\textrm{disc. jeans price}}$$

Second, the total paid is 84:

$$\underbrace{0.60B + 0.30J}_{\textrm{total paid}} =84$$

So you know

$$0.60B =12+0.30J$$
$$0.60B + 0.30J = 84$$

Now the first equation lets you represent the discounted cost of the blouse in terms of the discounted cost of the jeans; it says $12+0.30J$ is exactly the same thing as $0.60B$. So replacing $0.60B$ with $12+0.30J$ in the second equation, we can say
$$(12+0.30J)+0.30J = 84$$
Now this is easily solved for $J$ (which is our goal, the original price of the jeans):
$$12+0.30J + 0.30 J = 84$$
$$12+0.60J=84$$
$$0.60J = 72$$
$$J = 72/0.60$$
$$\boxed{J=120}$$

Comment: thank you for such a wonderful explanation :)

Comment: You're most welcome. The goal is to show that, if you are methodical, the problem isn't that hard. Just go one step at a time, turning the "real world" problem into a "math world" problem, which is much more easily solved, and then interpret your math answer in terms of the real problem.

Comment: You are right. I am actually preparing for one competitve exam, I ll keep your suggestion in mind-"One step at a time", thnx again :)